# JS: Assign variable value inside for loop depending on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add

```
if (obj1[i][0] !== d1 && row > -1) continue;
```

and

```
if (obj1[i][1] !== d2 && row > -1) continue;
```

depending on the value of `d1 and d2` but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

`if` statement acts as a filter it will allow only those values which assigned to `d1` or `d2` e.g if `d1=1` it will print only values with 1 and not all values in the table.

```
$("#session_id, #start_date").on('change', function() {
    var d1 = $( "#session_id" ).val();
    var d2 = $( "#start_date" ).val();

    $("#tbody").empty();


    if(d1 != null || d1 != undefined){
        kl1 = "if (obj1[i][0] !== d1 && row > -1) continue;";
        v(kl1);
    }

    if(d2 != null || d2 != undefined){
        var kl = "if (obj1[i][1] !== d2 && row > -1) continue;"
        v(kl);
    }

    function v(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
                data;
            row++;
        var newTr = table.insertRow(-1);
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][1]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][2]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][3]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][4]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][5]));
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Why your `if` statement are in quotes `""`. And what you expect you happen if the `continue` is called

Comment: `if` statement acts as a filter it will allow only those values which assigned to `d1` or `d2` e.g if `d1=1` it will print only 1 and not all values in table

Comment: You have a typo in your first if statement. You should have given parameter `kl1` to v function not `kl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is what you want. The way you're thinking to pass `statement` to `loop` actually doesn't work.

We can simplify the following code

```
d1 != null || d1 != undefined
```

by using javascript [truthy & falsey](https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/)

See the code below:

```
$("#session_id, #start_date").on('change', function() {
    var d1 = $( "#session_id" ).val();
    var d2 = $( "#start_date" ).val();

    $("#tbody").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
        if (d1 && obj1[i][0] !== d1 && row > -1) continue;
        if (d2 && obj1[i][1] !== d2 && row > -1) continue;
        row++;
        var newTr = table.insertRow(-1);
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][1]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][2]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][3]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][4]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][5]));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove statements out of the values and convert it to `Boolean` and pass it to the `function`

```
if(d1 != null || d1 != undefined){
        kl1 = obj1[i][0] !== d1 && row > -1
        v(kl1);
    }

    if(d2 != null || d2 != undefined){
        var kl = obj1[i][1] !== d2 && row > -1
        v(kl);
    }

    function v(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
                if(data) continue;
            row++;
            var newTr = table.insertRow(-1);
            newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][1]));
            newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][2]));
            newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][3]));
            newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][4]));
            newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][5]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: if I remove `""` from if statements im getting error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Answer (score 0):

The assignment that you are giving for k1 is string. Thats why instead of passing continue it is passing the whole statement. Please find below the way you can do.

```
if(d1 != null || d1 != undefined){
    if (obj1[i][0] !== d1 && row > -1) kl = "true";
    v(kl);
}

if(d2 != null || d2 != undefined){
    if (obj1[i][1] !== d2 && row > -1) kl =  "true"
    v(kl);
}

function v(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
            if(data=="true") continue
        row++;
    var newTr = table.insertRow(-1);
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][1]));
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][2]));
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][3]));
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][4]));
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj1[i][5]));
}
```

Comment: if you assign if statement to a variable it give error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Comment: Do it in this way
if (obj1[i][0] !== d1 && row > -1)  kl = "true";